# Can't run put udisks commands in udev scripts

Tags: udev, udisks

I'm trying to launch a script when a LUKS drive is inserted. So I setup a udev rule:

`KERNEL=="sd*3", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{serial}=="XXX", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="XXX", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/syncer-trigger /dev/%k"`

The script runs as normal user and calls `xce4-terminal` internally. Then the terminal emulator calls another script to decrypt the drive and mount it (with `udisksctl` command).

But `udisksctl` stuck, it seems to be waiting for udev to finish setting up the LUKS drive (The corresponding char device doesn't exist at this moment)

So, it formed a classic dead lock. Now how do I run a command `*AFTER*` the drive is settled?

P.S If I run xfce4-terminal in background (with nohup) and sleeps in the other script, udev would kill the xfce4-terminal window directly

**EDIT**

I tried `dbus-triggerd`:

```
./dbus-triggerd "type=signal,interface=org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor" -v --shell ./dump.sh
```

In dump.sh it just `echo "$@"`, I can see output from dbus-triggerd, but I'm seeing empty arguments here

The interface is correct, I can confirm that with

```
dbus-monitor interface=org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor
```

Comment: Random guess: maybe use `$devnode`/`%N` instead of `/dev/%k`. I believe $devnode should already be set up... E.g., that's how mdadm's rules do it: `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/sbin/mdadm --incremental $devnode --offroot"` ... but this is only a guess, and I'm not at all confident it will help. I wouldn't be surprised if udev won't process the next event (LUKS drive) until its done with the current event. In which case, need to find a way to get udev to not kill your terminal...

Comment: Oh, you could also try protecting your background terminal by running it through `setsid`, maybe that'll protect it from being killed by udev.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're down a level too deep in trying to do this with UDEV. Rather I'd try and do it with D-BUS instead.

I found this tutorial titled: [JACKdbus - Desktop integration - backend-switching](http://gareus.org/blog/jack2dbus) that discusses how, using `dbus-triggerd`. The tutorial is meant for OSX but should be adaptable to suit your Linux needs.

The key piece to this solution is [dbus-triggerd](http://gareus.org/oss/dbustriggerd/start).

Comment: Can you please check my update?